# Does using IAM policy with the following permission allow the user / group / role to do anything withing the aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1469200763880",
      "Action": [
        "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
        "iam:CreateRole"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Does Having a permission to create and attach permissions gives the entity power to do anything within an account, since it can attach improper roles to create any resource or perform any actions?
- If so, who should be responsible for that within an aws account?
- If so, it is as dangerous as using the root account, therefore, should I manage all permissions and then delete this policy?
- Are there more secure options?

Comment: What was the purpose behind creating this policy in the first place? It would appear to allow privilege escalation, for example if this IAM user has SSH access to an EC2 instance that was launched with a scoped-down S3 role, the iam:AttachRolePolicy would allow the IAM user to add the Administrator managed policy to the EC2 instance's role, and then effectively have Administrator permissions to the AWS account. Note that typically you should consider permissions boundaries for IAM users/roles.